# Type MCSessionState does not conform to protocol 'AnyObject'

Tags: ios, swift

I'm getting this error with the following code:

```
var dict: Dictionary<String, AnyObject> = [
    "peerID": peerID,
    "state": state
]
```

I'm using `MultipeerConnectivity`: peerID is of type MCPeerID (e.g., `MCPeerID(displayName: "morpheus")`), and state is MCSessionState (an enum, e.g., `MCSessionState.Connected`). Apparently, I cannot convert an enum to AnyObject? How can I solve this?

Best.

Edit: I tried using Dictionary<String, Any>, but now I get an exception in the next call. Here's the code:

```
func session(session: MCSession!, peer peerID: MCPeerID!, didChangeState state: MCSessionState) {

    var dict: Dictionary<String, Any> = [
        "peerID": peerID,
        "state": state
    ]

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(
        "MCDidChangeStateNotification",
        object: nil,
        userInfo: dict
    )
}
```

Xcode indicates the "userInfo: dict" line with the exception:

```
Thread 10: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)
```

Maybe this won't tell you much, so what could I post that would help?

Edit:

By inspecting the object at runtime (after the crash), this is what I get:

```
state   MultipeerConnectivity.MCSessionState    Connecting  Connecting
dict    Swift.Dictionary<Swift.String, protocol<>>      
    [0] Swift._DictionaryElement<Swift.String, protocol<>>      
         key    Swift.String    "state" 
             core   Swift._StringCore       
         value  protocol<>      
             payload_data_0 Builtin.RawPointer  0x0 
             payload_data_1 Builtin.RawPointer  0x0 
             payload_data_2 Builtin.RawPointer  0x0 
             instance_type  Builtin.RawPointer  0x0
```

There seem to be some null pointers there, but the "state" variable seems fine...

Note: I commented out the peerID assignment.

Comment: That looks like a compiler error to me. If it is that, there probably isn't much you can do (except filing a radar).

Comment: @Lukas not a compiler error, he's just trying to do something that cannot be done. See my answer.

Comment: @AbhiBeckert Yes, you're right. Still, the compiler should tell him that, not crash/produce crashing code.

Comment: @Lukas I guess, but they have more important things to work on. The console log tells you it crashed inside "_convertDictionaryToNSDictionary" so I think it would be immediately obvious to anyone who understands how the the runtime works. It also crashes even if you store an object in the `Any` value, so it will never make it into production.

Comment: You are right, and I am new to both swift (obviously) and objective-c, so I don't understand the runtime very well yet. But shouldn't this be a compile time error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Apparently, I cannot convert an enum to AnyObject? How can I solve this?

That's correct, AnyObject cannot contain enums.

> I tried using `Dictionary<String, Any>`, but now I get an exception in the next call.

NSNotificationCentre doesn't take a swift `Dictionary`, it takes an `NSDictionary`.

Wherever possible, `Dictionary` and `NSDictionary` are inter-operable however `NSDictionary` can only have objects as the key and value. You cannot use `Any` in a dictionary that needs to be treated as if it were an `NSDictionary` by an obj-c API such as `NSNotificationCentre`.

So, long story short, a notification userInfo dictionary has to be `Dictionary<AnyObject, AnyObject>` (or `<String, String>` or something that is an object). You're going to have to use something other than an Enum.

Comment: I did notice that the first method in the stack trace was trying to convert Dictionary to NSDictionary. I'll try wrapping that enum in a class and see where it goes.

Comment: I created a wrapper for the enum and used Dictionary<String, AnyObject>. Worked like a charm! Thank you.

Comment: No worries. Pretty much any struct used by Apple has a function like `NSStringFromCGRect()` for use cases like this one. You can also use `NSValue` which can hold arbitrary bytes: `[NSValue value:&struct withObjCType:@encode(MyCStruct)]` (sorry, I'm not sure how to do that in Swift, if it's even possible at all — the `@encode()` compiler instruction may not exist).

Answer (score 3):

`AnyObject` is only for class types, use `Any` to also support enums (cf. [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TypeCasting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH22-XID_448)).

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use type `Any` for the dictionary values (because AnyObject can only be used for an instance of a class):

This worked in a playground for me:

```
var dict: Dictionary<String, Any> = [
    "peerID": peerID,
    "state": state
];
```