# (Swift) Extra argument 'userinfo' in call

Tags: swift, dictionary, nsdictionary, nsnotificationcenter

When I'm passing the "userInfo" variable to the parameter "userInfo" of the function "postNotificationName("String", object:, userInfo:)", I get this error : **Extra argument 'userinfo' in call** & I don't really know how to fix it !

```
 func session(session: MCSession!, peer peerID: MCPeerID!, didChangeState state: MCSessionState) {
    var userInfo: Dictionary<String, Any> = ["peerID": peerID, "state": state]

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),
        { () -> Void in
            NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("MPCDemo_DidChangeStateNotification", object: nil, userInfo: userInfo)
        })
}
```

In the Objective-C version of this method, they use "@(...)" for the "state" value, but I don't know what does it mean & how to call that in Swift!

```
NSDictionary *userInfo = @{ @"peerID": peerID, @"state": @(state) };
```

If someone could help me, it would be awesome ! ^^

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
var userInfo : [NSObject : AnyObject] = ["peerID": peerID, "state": state]

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),
{ () -> Void in
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("MPCDemo_DidChangeStateNotification", object: nil, userInfo: userInfo)
})
```

Comment: Doesn't work ! I get this error now : 
**Type 'MCSessionState' does not conform to protocol 'AnyObject'**

Comment: Apologies, I got that bit wrong. Please see this thread, that will give you some idea. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24109982/type-mcsessionstate-does-not-conform-to-protocol-anyobject